# Apache2 - Action 'start' failed. "fork: Cannot allocate memory"

Tags: linux, memory, debian, apache-http-server

I'm unable to start apache2 due to memory issue.

service apache2 start

```
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information. 
failed!
```

tail -n 100 /var/log/apache2/error.log

```
fork: Cannot allocate memory
unable to fork new process
```

This is the output of my apache2.conf file

```
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers        150
    MinSpareServers      10
    MaxSpareServers     150
    MaxClients          150
    MaxRequestsPerChild   2000
</IfModule>
```

Any ideas? :)

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

How much RAM do you have on your server?

It seems that your 'StartServers' variable is set too high.

StartServers – this is how many Apache instances should start when Apache is started on your server.

Set it to a lower value, for example 10 or so, and your should be able to start the Apache service.

Comment: Also, if this is it, I would strongly suggest lowering `MaxSpareServers` and possibly `MaxClients` as well.